# Aframe - Use Google Cardboard Settings?

Tags: aframe, distortion, headset, webvr, krpano

When an app is opened that uses Google Cardboard, the distortion is adjusted for the particular headset the user has configured (Cardboard A, Cardboard B, C-1 Glass, Daydream, Viewmaster, etc.)

With Aframe, there seems to only be one kind of lens view, which makes Aframe experiences look pretty bad with certain headsets. Anyone know a good way to handle this? For example, is there any way to do any of the following:

1. Have Aframe use existing Google Cardboard settings?
2. Set up toggles so that a user may select their Cardboard headset within Aframe?
3. Manually make adjustments like in [Krpano tours' VR Setup](https://krpano.com/krpanocloud/webvr/?v=119pr8)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't believe Cardboard settings aren't accessible through the browser. The settings would have to be provided and built into the WebVR API spec.

A-Frame just uses a polyfill for browsers. Most mobile browser and especially Cardboard holders do not have true WebVR support. I would not expect much from mobile Web Cardboard.

We also won't be too open in cluttering A-Frame or spending time with Cardboard-related code. While it's fun for makers, it's not the way VR is going heading forward. However, application developers are free to build that logic into their own applications.

Comment: good to know. thanks kevin. is aframe interested in Daydream or GearVR, particularly in using the hand controllers?

Comment: Yes, there are PRs for Daydream / GearVR controllers by Michael Chen. There are also already components in the community for Daydream controls. They'll be there for people to use. GearVR controllers dependent on us receiving dev kits.